# How to configure PXE/Tftp in dhcp.conf on vmware Fusion 7 Pro with static reservations

Tags: dhcp, pxe-boot, vmware-fusion

I'm senior devops engineer with a deployment system to ship a couple thousand linux machines a week. I'm using vmware fusion 7 pro to do this, and I'm having a little trouble with pxe booting.

I ran into this little issue, so I thought i'd do a quick writeup to maybe save someone 15 mins. If someone knows a better way, I'd love to hear it.

I'm playing with PXE booting some containers. I want VMware Fusion to handle DHCP, and I want the VM's to be Nat'ed with my Mac for outside access, thus I need to use vmnet8 by default. I also have several virtual machines that should have static reservations to mimic the production network this system will reside on. So, I edit /Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/vmnet8/dhcpd.conf

I need to add two simple lines to the subnet declaration for tftp:

```
  next-server 192.168.87.20;  
  filename "pxelinux.0";
```

The problem is the subnet declaration (line 26 of the stock file) is in the forbidden zone:

```
###### VMNET DHCP Configuration. Start of "DO NOT MODIFY SECTION" #####
```

If you change stuff in the forbidden zone then restart vmware fusion, or restart its networking, it rudely replaces the whole dhcpd.conf file with an auto-generated one. It does rotate the existing one to a backup, but only one rotation (3 would be less rude, so would a prompt and a log entry).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is How To Add the PXE Boot Configuration in the relevant VMware Fusion dhcp.conf file.**

The "proper" solution is to simply redeclare the whole subnet block below the "DO NOT MODIFY" section. So, to add the next-server and filename options for PXE booting, I had to add the following:

```
####### VMNET DHCP Configuration. End of "DO NOT MODIFY SECTION" #######  
subnet 192.168.87.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {  
  range 192.168.87.128 192.168.87.254;  
  option broadcast-address 192.168.87.255;  
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.87.2;  
  option domain-name localdomain;  
  default-lease-time 1800;                # default is 30 minutes  
  max-lease-time 7200;                    # default is 2 hours  
  option netbios-name-servers 192.168.87.2;  
  option routers 192.168.87.2;  
  next-server 192.168.87.20;  
  filename "pxelinux.0";  
}  
#  
host cmhpxe {  
   hardware ethernet 00:0C:29:DF:06:7F;  
   fixed-address  192.168.87.20;  
}  
#
```

The fun way to reconfigure and restart DHCP without restarting fusion:

```
alias vm_restartdhcpd='sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --configure ;   
sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --stop;   
sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --start'
```